Spring kafka batch listener get custom header
        @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
//        return new JsonMessageConverter();
        JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new JsonMessageConverter();
        jsonMessageConverter.setHeaderMapper(new CustomKafkaHeaderMapper());
        return jsonMessageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchMessagingMessageConverter batchConverter() {
//        return new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter());
        BatchMessagingMessageConverter batchMessagingMessageConverter = new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter());
        batchMessagingMessageConverter.setHeaderMapper(new CustomKafkaHeaderMapper());
        return batchMessagingMessageConverter;
    }

    public class CustomKafkaHeaderMapper extends DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper {

        @Override
        public void toHeaders(Headers source, Map<String, Object> target) {
            super.toHeaders(source, target);
            if (!target.containsKey("cushion_next_retry_attempt")) {
                target.put("cushion_next_retry_attempt", 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void fromHeaders(MessageHeaders headers, Headers target) {
            super.fromHeaders(headers, target);
            if (headers.containsKey("cushion_next_retry_attempt")) {
                Integer nextRetryAttempt = headers.get("cushion_next_retry_attempt", Integer.class);
                target.add("cushion_next_retry_attempt", new byte[] {nextRetryAttempt.byteValue()});
            }
        }
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.id}",
            topics = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.topic.linkage}", autoStartup = "false",
            batch = "true",
            groupId = "cushion",
            concurrency = "4")
    @Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
    public void listen(List<CancelAuthorizationLinkage> messages,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) List<String> keys,
                       @Header(
                               value = "cushion_next_retry_attempt",
                               required = false
                       )
                       List<Integer> nextRetryAttempts) throws InvalidValueException {
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
            CancelAuthorizationLinkage message = messages.get(i);
            String key = keys.get(i);
            int nextRetryAttempt = nextRetryAttempts.get(i);
            try {
                processor.process(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, CancelAuthorizationLinkage>> handle =
                        retryHandler.handle(message, listenerPropertiesService, e, nextRetryAttempt, key);
            }
        }
    }
}

I’m using a Spring Kafka batch listener. Not all of my messages contain the next_retry_attempt header. This header is added only when a message consumption fails and is re-sent to the topic, to track retry attempts and determine if further retries are needed. However, I find that the next_retry_attempt header is always null in the listener. How can I configure it correctly so that it defaults to 0 if the header is missing?



What is relevance between expected in the listener method cushion_next_retry_attempt and that next_retry_attempt you populated in the CustomKafkaHeaderMapper?

@ArtemBilan Sorry, that was a typo. I have updated my question. I tried adding my CustomKafkaHeaderMapper to both RecordMessageConverter and BatchMessagingMessageConverter, but it still doesn’t work and returns null.

You cannot extract custom headers for the batch like that:
                   @Header(
                           value = "cushion_next_retry_attempt",
                           required = false
                   )
                   List<Integer> nextRetryAttempts

You have to look into a dedicated header for that purpose:
KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS as a List<Map<String, Object>>

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/headers.html

With the batch converter, the converted headers are available in the KafkaHeaders.BATCH_CONVERTED_HEADERS as a List<Map<String, Object>> where the map in a position of the list corresponds to the data position in the payload.


Thank you very much. You also previously answered my question about Spring Kafka Test, and I wanted to express my gratitude again.
I tested it locally, and I found that for batches, I only need to add the headerMapper to the BatchMessagingMessageConverter. There is no need to add it to the RecordMessageConverter.
